# Images not inline in TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

Please find screenshot of how images are appearing as a result of TCPDF in PHP. Images I am bringing from MySQL using a correct MySQL query. I have tried so so so much but unable to get images inline in one row adjacent to each other. They are appearing like one up and one down or one up and one at down-right so on.

Code to generate the PDF:

```
if (isset($_POST['submits'])){
require_once 'includes/practice.php';
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 12);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(50);
//$pdf->AddPage('L','A4');
include('connect.php');
$emp_id = $_POST['formid'];
// $sql="SELECT * FROM inspection WHERE date='$emp_number'"; 
//$results = $link->query("SELECT * FROM inspection_files WHERE formid='$emp_id'");

// Whenever you want to view files; run this query
                        // Get images from the database
                        $getFiles = $link->query("SELECT * FROM inspection_files WHERE formid=$emp_id");
                        if($getFiles->num_rows > 0){

                            while($row = $getFiles->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"];
                                $images.="<li>".'<img src="'.$imageURL.'" width="150" />'."</li>";
                            }

                        } else {
                            echo '<p>No image(s) found...</p>';


                        }

   $pdf->writeHTML($images, true, false, false, false, '');
  ob_end_clean();
  $pdf->Output('Report.pdf', 'D');

}
```

"Screenshot:" https://i.imgur.com/a/62nY9oO

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), though none of what you had capitalized needs emphasis.

Comment: Sure Thanks for correction..

Comment: Why are you using multple crappy image hosts? Images often get deleted on those providers. Stack Overflow has an official image hosting partnership with Imgur. Please use that instead by uploading images in the question editor.

Comment: I guess we need reputation for that don't we? I tried once some time before wasn't able to do that.